# UINavigationItem: Create a "nextBarButtonItem" (= rightBarButtonItem with arrow)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

there are 3 Bar-Buttons in the UINavigationItem:

- backBarButtonItem
- leftBarButtonItem
- rightBarButtonItem

But there is no "nextBarButtonItem" (= rightBarButtonItem with arrow). How can I create it? Do I need an own image with an arrow? How can I put the image in the rightBarButtonItem? Or is there a better way without image?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way is to use a bar button item with a custom image with that next-button look, and set it as `rightBarButtonItem`. Apple doesn't provide any `nextBarButtonItem` functionality due to the way a navigation controller works.

If you look carefully at the Now Playing button in the iPod app it's also custom-designed.

Comment: Thanks! How can I build my own UIBarButtonItem? I need a second image for the click-effect, too. "UIBarButtonItem initwithImage" is not the right, I think I need "UIBarButtonItem initWithCustomView", but how I have to construct the UIView?

Comment: @Manni: You can use a `UIButton` and set those images for its normal and highlighted states.

Answer (score 1):

Check three20 library used to create Facebook app for iPhone.

https://github.com/facebook/three20

Comment: Thanks! I use this library in my project already :-) In the example TTCatalog is a great forward button. But a TTButton is a UIControl and I need a UIBarButtonItem... Is it possible to add a TTButton in the UINavigationBar?

Comment: Bellow is sample for adding back button
TTButton* button = [TTButton buttonWithStyle:@"toolbarBackButton:" title:@"Back"];
 [button setFrame:CGRectMake(9, 7, 65, 33)];
 [button addTarget:target action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:button];

Comment: Yeah, I got it this way:  
TTButton *forwardButtonView = [TTButton buttonWithStyle:@"toolbarForwardButton:" title:@"Next"];  

[forwardButtonView addTarget:self action:@selector(btnNextPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];  

[forwardButtonView sizeToFit];  

UIBarButtonItem *forwardButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:forwardButtonView];  

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = forwardButton;  

[forwardButton release];